# Do threads share some class fields?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety

This is an example from C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4

I have a thread class:

```
    class Thread : public QThread {

    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Thread();
        void setMessage(const QString &message);
        void stop();

    protected:
        void run();

    private: 
        QString messageStr;
        volatile bool stopped;

}
```

This is the relevant implementation of the the class:

```
Thread::Thread() {
    stopped = false;
}

void Thread::run() {

    while (!stopped)
        std::cerr << qPrintable(messageStr);
    stopped = false;
    std::cerr << std::endl;

}

void Thread::stop() {  
    stopped = true;   
}
```

This class is used in a ThreadDialog class which basically have two private fields Thread `threadA` and Thread `threadB`. `setMessage` function is called separately for them and `messageStr` is set to "A" and "B". Two buttons are declared inside which have clicked signals connected two to slot functions that start or stop those two threads like this:

```
void ThreadDialog::startOrStopThreadA() {

    if (threadA.isRunning()) {
        threadA.stop();
        threadAButton->setText(tr("Start A"));
    } else {
        threadA.start();
        threadAButton->setText(tr("Stop A"));
    }

}
```

The function for threadB is the same. The problem is this, quoting directly from the book: "The stopped variable is declared volatile because it is accessed from different threads and we want to be sure that it is freshly read every time it is needed. If we omitted the volatile keyword, the compiler might optimize access to the variable, possibly leading to incorrect results."

I can't understand why these two threads would access the same field. Aren't they different instances so they have their own field `stopped`? Furthermore if `stopped` field is shared why isn't `messageStr` field shared too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't understand why these two threads would access the same field. Aren't they different instances 
>   so they have their own field stopped? Furthermore if stopped field is shared why isn't messageStr 
>   field shared too?

That's not what they are saying. The field is not shared among different instances, regardless of whether there are threads involved or not. However an instance might be accessed from different threads, in that regard, the fields might be "shared" among different threads.

They are talking about the case when some other thread wishes to call `threadA.stop()`

If you have this code:

```
Thread threadA;
threadA.start();
... 
threadA.stop();
```

There are 2 threads involved:

1. The thread that runs the above code
2. The newly created `threadA` that is started with the `threadA.start()` call

Now `volatile bool stopped` is accessed by thread 2 in it's `run()` function, and it's accessed from thread 1 when it calls `threadA.stop()`.

Comment: So I have a main thread that calls run and stop but the actual run functions are executed by threadA and threadB, so I have 3 threads, right?

Comment: If you create 2 instances of your Thread class and call the .start() function on them , then yes, you have 2 new threads in addition to the one that created those 2 threads.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common confusion in multithreading. You are confusing the thread object `class Thread : public QThread` with the thread of execution (ie executing instructions).

- There is one thread of execution which is running the code `ThreadDialog::startOrStopThreadA`
- There is another thread of execution which is running `Thread::run()` and which is started by `threadA.start()`.

Both of these threads have access to `messageStr` and `stopped`

Answer (score 0):

The two instances `threadA` and `threadB` do not share `stopped`. They are different instances if a same class.

About this statement :

> The stopped variable is declared volatile because it is accessed from
>   different threads and we want to be sure that it is freshly read every
>   time it is needed.

It means that the `stopped` variable is accessed from two different running threads. Here the two threads are the main application thread and the one in the `run()` function. It's unsafe to access the same variable from two different threads.